# How to Use Google Calendar API

Tags: android, api, calendar

I am new to android programming and was just able to use the Google Calendar API. However, I am not sure how to invoke the API. My application requires two devices. One that will be able to create events, and the other to just view them. Should I invoke the api by Sending HTTP requests and parsing the responses, or by using client libraries? Is there any good tutorials available? So far, I have only been able to find training on how to create events, but not how to display the actual calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Using client libraries would be much easier. I suggest that you can install the Google plugin in eclipse, and then use it to import the Calendar api. And here you can find the android sample to try it out. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3